# GCE Snapshots via Commandline

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

When trying to create a snapshot via the command line on GCE (i.e google cloud) I get the following errors,

```
[root@william001 ~]# gcloud compute --project "####" disks snapshot "https://clients6.google.com/compute/v1/projects/####/zones/europe-west1-b/disks/william001" --zone "europe-west1-b" --snapshot-names "snapshot-2"
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.disks.snapshot) could not parse resource: [https://clients6.google.com/compute/v1/####/zones/europe-west1-b/disks/william001]
```

Any ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using the equivalent command line that you get in the Developers Console. As Fabricio suggested, run the command as

```
gcloud compute --project "####" disks snapshot william001 --zone "europe-west1-b" --snapshot-names "snapshot-2"
```

Comment: The issue has been fixed, I ran the equivalent command line and it's working

Answer (score 0):

Try using "william001" only as your disk name.